# Does Jest Client support Cluster name?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have implemented elasticsearch with native client. This is my implementation:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
```

Now I want to implement the same with Jest client. I have created the client, but I am missing cluster name:

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
factory.setHttpClientConfig(
    new HttpClientConfig
    .Builder("http://127.0.0.1:9301")
    .multiThreaded(true)
    .build()
);

JestClient client = factory.getObject();
```

Is there any way to implement with cluster name?

Comment: Jest uses the HTTP protocol since it's hitting the REST API, hence you don't need to specify the cluster name like you do with the native `TransportClient` does. Do you have any troubles connecting to your ES server? Also make sure to use the port 9201 and not 9301

Comment: I have connected ES server successfully. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest uses the HTTP protocol since it's hitting the REST API, hence you don't need to specify the cluster name like you do with the native TransportClient does.

Also make sure to use the port 9201 and not 9301